# Report does not fetch current data in C# windows form?

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am making a bill report project in window form in C#. When i click on print button ,my report viewer form can not fetch my current data from database which means that when I start application and insert values in the database then my report viewer can not fetch the latest  values. But, when I close my application and re open report, then it fetch all data including my last transaction value.

How can i fetch my current values on click of my print button.
I tried but it does not not work on current values.

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    cn = new SqlConnection(databaseconnection);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Bill_Detail order by billId DESC", cn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
    da.Fill(ds);
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
    this.Customer_detailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.Customer_detail,id); 
    this.Bill_DetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.Bill_Detail, id);   
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: Please provide [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether 'save data in report' is enabled in report settings. Uncheck this option if this is a crystal report.
2. The second option is to right click your report-> go to Design->Default Settings->Reporting tab and **verify that 'Discard Save Data when loading reports is checked'**

[image]

Comment: I am using rdlc report viewer not crystal report.Plz give me idea on report viewer.

Comment: @user3480008 Have you rebuild your project? Also take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587103/rdlc-report-data-doesnt-update-to-reflect-changes

Comment: No..i still use report viewer control.

Comment: @user3480008 Can you update your original question with the code you are using after update and initial load of your report?

Comment: private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{cn = new SqlConnection(databaseconnection);
da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Bill_Detail order by billId DESC", cn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
     this.Customer_detailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.Customer_detail,id);
           this.Bill_DetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.Bill_Detail, id);
            
             this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
         }

Comment: when i click on print button that is on Form1 data is inserted in Db but billid releted data is not displayed on report viewer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DataView dview = new DataView();
        dview.Table = LoadReport().Tables["StudTable"];
ItemsReport myreport = new ItemsReport();
        myreport.SetDataSource(dview); 
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(_connString);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Bill_Detail order by billId DESC", myConn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "StudTable");
return ds;
```