# How to Update Dataset for RDLC Reports

Tags: dataset, rdlc, strongly-typed-dataset

I have created `DataSet` for `RDLC` reports. Now i have changed my `Stored Procedure` by adding some new `Columns` to it. `DataSet` contains different `Stored Procedures`, now how can i update the `DataSet` with out deleting and Re Creating it. So that new added `Columns` are available on `DataSet` for use.

Comment: Updating the rdlc file manually is the only solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/58740512/591656

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have solved it..

- Open `DataSet`
- Right Click on Required `Stored Procedure`.
- Clicked On `Configure`.
- Click `Next, Next` and `Finish`.

Now go to `RDLC` Report.

- Right Click on the `Dataset` and click `Refresh`.

Comment: What about when editing from Visual Studio? There is no option to refresh Datasets that I can find. If someone notices this comment, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It took me a while to find, but by following the above instructions using the Solutions explorer, double clicking on the .xsd file for the dataset, it'll then open a new window which you can carry on from the 2nd/3rd step above.

Comment: @topher, helpful..Thanks

Comment: To refresh the dataset in VS2015: Open your RDLC > Click on the tablix > Open View on the top menu bar, at the bottom you'll see Report Data Open it, in the new pane you will see datasets folder expand it, click your dataset and refresh! Credit this guy => http://www.codeease.com/about-update-dataset-for-a-rdlc-file-in-visual-studio-2010.html

Comment: I am using VS2013 and I have create DataSet using class. I have create new field in DataSet. I have tried to update in report but failed. How I can update DataSet in report help please.

Comment: Open report file (rdlc file), right click on dataset and click refresh or reselect the table from dataset in report file. It will refresh column in report file.

Answer (score 27):

In visual studio if you have the RDLC open you can open the Report Data window by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

From here you click on datasets and then right click on the data set to refresh it.

Comment: You've made my day. For more than 3 hours I've been struggling with a report. Now it works :D VS 2019 CTRL + ALT + D and Refresh

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2017, you can right click on the Dataset, select Dataset Properties,  Click on Refreash Fields, then click on OK.  You should see the updated dataset in the Report Data navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Attention when editing / updating the data source of RDLC files, these are fixed in the file structure *, that is, if you use the "same path" for the source repository, the update will work correctly, otherwise it will be necessary to open the file RDLC in XML / TXT format and manually change the parameter below:

C: \ git \ repo \ application \ report \ dataSource.xsd

After saving the file, you can update the report's datasource.